# Action Bar styling [Top and Bottom]

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I am a beginner in android development,
I am trying to style action bar in top and bottom
like this in top 
[Action Bar Top](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdtsyjfx81or8nd/ActionTop.PNG?dl=0)
[image]

and bottom
[Action Bar Bottom](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kp5tya8cvszleif/actio%20bottom.PNG?dl=0)
[image]

I have using splitActionBarWhenNarrow to split action bar...
but I am unable to style action bar and show custom button in left or right side of action bar..
How do I achieve this?
I am using API 15 as a minimum requirement

any suggestion will be appreciated..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XfDDfa3rv8

Comment: Use new ToolBar for Tabs. you can put them any where you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new Toolbar introduced in material design, rather than using ActionBar.
You can create your own Style.xml file with styles for customization.

Comment: is it supported in API level 15?

Comment: look up "design support library"

Comment: @scienticious Yes.it is minSdk=7